# How to prevent TextArea to go new line?

Tags: html

I had used html **textarea**

```
<textarea runat="server" cols="1" rows="1" aria-expanded="false"  aria-haspopup="true" ID="txt_monthlyemployee"  EnableViewState="false" class="comment-tabs2" ></textarea>
```

I want when I finished from writing on the **textarea** and click enter the **textarea** doesn't go to new line .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textarea` basically represents a `multi-line` plain-text editing control.

If you want it to be in single line then `simple input text` will be sufficient.

```
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: but it keep with the old values how to prevent that